# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate a map with some RichMarkers on it. When I call the map, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

This seems to prevent the creation of RichMarker markers. The code so far is very basic, I've been interacting with the console to make tests.

```
function init() {
    emap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('emap'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.512, -73.576),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // A simple RichMarker test
    var marker = new RichMarker({  
        map: emap,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.512, -73.576),
        content: "<div>Hello</div>"
    });
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

The page link is http://agorametropolitaine.com/evenements. Thanks for your help!

Comment: uhh... which line? Also, isn't the error message kinda descriptive of what you're doing wrong?

Comment: I know it's descriptive. The same code works fine in a sandboxed page, but it looks like some other script on the page is messing with it. I can't pinpoint where.


    Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
    (anonymous function)
    Nf.main main.js:41
    (anonymous function) main.js:24
    (anonymous function) main.js:10
    (anonymous function) main.js:24
    K main.js:9
    (anonymous function) main.js:24
    Jf.(anonymous function).df main.js:23
    Kf.(anonymous function).ad main.js:24
    Of main.js:24
    (anonymous function) %7Bcommon,util,stats%7D.js:1 </code>

Comment: I figured it out. Some other script was calling Leaflet.js.. It didn't occur to me that it was using Google Maps too..

Comment: Please either delete your question or post a descriptive answer yourself (it's OK to answer your own question) so others don't spend time trying to figure this out (like I just did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seemed to be collision between Leaflet.js and the Google Maps Api. I got rid of the Leaflet code as I didn't need it anymore (from an old implementation, moved everything to Google Maps Api).

I don't know how/if it can be fixed easily, and I didn't investigate further.